# Custom posts Drop down menu problem - wordpress

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

Im try this code to get my custom posts list in drop down in sidebar.

```
 <form action="<? bloginfo('url'); ?>" method="get">
 <select name="page_id" id="page_id">
 <?php
 global $post;
 $args = array( 'post_type'=>'name',
'numberposts' => -1
 );
 $posts = get_posts($args);
 foreach( $posts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
                <option value="<? echo $post->ID; ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></option>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
 </select>
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="view" />
 </form>
```

Every thing nice code get the list of my custom posts and also show in drop down. but the visit button not work in my code. when i pick name from drop down and click on visit its just redirect to home page not to post. please help me. 
One More thing can we make this like that if user pick name from drop down menu user automatic redirect  to that post, I mean user dont need to click on visit button. anyways both answers welcome. thanks in advance.(sorry for bad English)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please Try this

```
<select name="page_id" id="page_id" onChange="this.options[this.selectedIndex].value && (window.location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
    <?php
    global $post;
    $args = array( 'post_type'=>'name',
    'numberposts' => -1
    );
    $posts = get_posts($args);
    foreach( $posts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
        <option value="<? echo get_the_permalink($post->ID); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can take help of javaScript.
Below illustration will help you to get the desired result.
When the user selects the option, the page automatically will be redirected to the post.

```
<select onchange="javascript:location.href = this.value;">
    <?php
        foreach ($posts as $post) {
            setup_postdata($post);
            echo '<option value="'.the_permalink().'" >'.the_title().' </option>';
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for help, but its show just the_title in all drop down values.

Comment: check now I have updated the code. I forgot to put parenthesis after the_title.

Comment: Thanks for help , anyways above code given by jogi help me .. thanks for your time